# How to add a Code128 barcode font to SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

Hello I have used this very useful [Adding Barcode to Report Builder 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410327/adding-barcode-to-report-builder-3-0) until today with my Microsoft Report Builder - Version 12.0.6024.0. It works like a charm with no issues but now I'm in need of upgrading my reports into a newer version of Microsoft Report Builder - Version 15.0.19611.0. For some reason the barcodes does not show up in the newer version. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Have you installed the font in c:\windows\fonts for both the report server and the client?

Comment: Yes I installed the same fonts to the new server which I'm using in my current server, and the client is still the same.