# Why is the SSRS Barcode breaks up with a space in between?

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, system.drawing, ssrs-2016

I have a SSRS report which I've initially created with `SQL Server 2014` Report Builder (12.0.6024.0) using Code128 according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410327/adding-barcode-to-report-builder-3-0). It has been working great until we wanted to upgrade our `SQL Server to 2016` and then I made the same report using SQL Server 2016 Report Builder (15.0.19611.0).

Now the issue is the new version does not support that custom code which I got from above mentioned post. After installing many Code128 fonts found one of them that works but it did not like all other fonts and barcodes won't show up.

So it would look like following figure
[image]

As the counter attack I installed that previously mentioned working one Code128 font which is `IDAutomationC128L` and turns out it works really until I realize this one glitch. As you can see in the bottom picture I compared the working version(2014) with the new version (2016) the glitch is there is a space in the middle of the barcode, sometimes it's in the `Item Number` field and sometimes it's under `Raw Material Item Number` field.

Here's the SQL Server 2014 version(Code128) for the same parameter
[image]

Here's the SQL Server 2016 version(IDAutomationC128L) for the same parameter
[image]

Does anybody know how to fix that issue? I have tried couple of other things too just to make sure, such as attaching the newest .NET version's(4.8.4390.0) System.Drawing.dll just becuase I thought SQL Server 2016 might not support .NET version 2.0(which I'm using for SQL Server 2014)

Appreciate all your support!

Comment: Do you really need your custom code? I installed the Code128 font and set a textbox to that font and it worked as expected, showing the barcode in place of the text.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes you're correct, it will show a barcode, but not the correct barcode tho. Ex : If the barcode's real value you entered is 1234 what you will get after scan is some random number that doesn't have to do anything with the real value. I believe the custom code adds some checksum bits and all to correctly convert the value to barcode.